# Add new step checkout in magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout

Url ex: http://magentotest.dev/checkout

This is my problems:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution which worked for us

```
define(
    [
        'ko',
        'uiComponent',
        'underscore',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
    ],
    function (
        ko,
        Component,
        _,
        stepNavigator
    ) {
        'use strict';
        /**
        *
        * newcheckout - is the name of the component's .html template, 
        * MD_Newcheckoutstep  - is the name of the your module directory.
        * 
        */
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'MD_Newcheckoutstep/newcheckout'
            },

            //add here your logic to display step,
            // I have given false here so that is will no merge with other step
            // if you make it true sometime happens that is merge with shipping step.
            visible: ko.observable(quote.isVirtual())

            /**
            *
            * @returns {*}
            */
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
                // register your step
                stepNavigator.registerStep(
                    //step code will be used as step content id in the component template
                    'newcheckoutstep',
                    //step alias
                    null,
                    //step title value
                    'New Checkout Step',
                    //observable property with logic when display step or hide step
                    this.isVisible,

                    _.bind(this.navigate, this),

                    /**
                    * sort order value
                    * 'sort order value' < 10: step displays before shipping step;
                    * 10 < 'sort order value' < 20 : step displays between shipping and payment step
                    * 'sort order value' > 20 : step displays after payment step
                    */
                    15
                );

                return this;
            },

            /**
            * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between checkout step
            * during checkout. You can add custom logic, for example some conditions
            * for switching to your custom step 
            */
            navigate: function () {
               self.visible(true);
            },

            /**
            * @returns void
            */
            navigateToNextStep: function () {
                stepNavigator.next();
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Here is more detail about this solution [on my own blog](http://blog.m2doctor.com/add-new-checkout-step/)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have added "New Step" yourself, this just means that you are at step 2 "Shipping".
Without posting what you have written, we won't be able to tell what is wrong but I suggest you have a look at calling the CSS class in your code:
`.opc-progress-bar-item._active`

Comment: Yes. I was add new step at first step. So I want my new step is active and  Shipping is not active when I go to checkout page.
It's so difficult for me. Can you send me example for this?

Comment: I have just fixed my problem.
I was custom file /js/view/shipping.js.
Edit visble in initialize function:

`visible: ko.observable(quote.isVirtual())`

And add set visible = true in navigate function.
`navigate: function () {
    //load data from server for shipping step
    var self = this;
    self.visible(true);
 },`

thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is how I solved it. 
Shipping step is marked as visible because it is the first one by default, so the solution is to change its **visible** property to false.

I used a [Javascript mixin](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html) instead of overwriting the whole file:

Declare Mixin: *Vendor/Module/view/base/requirejs-config.js*

```
var config = {
'config': {
    'mixins': {
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping': {
            'Vendor_Module/js/view/shipping-mixin': true
        }
    }
}
```

};

The mixin file: *Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-mixin.js*

```
define(
[
    'ko'
], function (ko) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {

        initialize: function () {
            this.visible = ko.observable(false); //set visible to be initially false
            this._super();

            return this;
        }
    };

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    };
}
);
```

Additionally, you have to do the same for payment as that is the first step on virtual orders.